# Longest Length sub array with elements in a given range

Tags: algorithm

If I have a list of integers, in an array, how do I find the length of the longest sub array, such that the difference between the minimum and maximum element of that array is less than a given integer, say M.

So if we had an array with 3 elements,

[1, 2, 4]

And if M were equal to 2

Then the longest subarry would be [1, 2]

Because if we included 4, and we started from the beginning, the difference would be 3, which is greater than M ( = 2), and if we started from 2, the difference between the largest (4) and smallest element (2) would be 2 and that is not less than 2 (M)

The best I can think of is to start from the left, then go as far right as possible without the sub array range getting too high. Of course at each step we have to keep track of the minimum and maximum element so far. This has an n squared time complexity though, can't we get it faster?

Comment: Please edit your post and show us example input and output, and your attempts to solve the problem as well.

Comment: I believe it can be done in O(n*logn). Do you have any space constrains?

Comment: How?............

Comment: @Rockstar5645 is this worked for you?

Comment: Please gimme a minute, I'm still trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following idea:

Let create MaxLen array (size of n) which define as: MaxLen[i] = length of the max sub-array till the i-th place.

After we will fill this array it will be easy (O(n)) to find your max sub-array.

How do we fill the MaxLen array? Assume you know MaxLen[i], What will be in MaxLen[i+1]?

We have 2 option - if the number in originalArr[i+1] do not break your constrains of exceed diff of m in the longest sub-array ending at index i then `MaxLen[i+1] = MaxLen[i] + 1` (because we just able to make our previous sub array little bit longer. In the other hand, if originalArr[i+1] bigger or smaller with diff m with one of the last sub array we need to find the element that has diff of m and (let call its index is k) and insert into `MaxLen[i+1] = i - k + 1` because our new max sub array will have to exclude the originalArr[k] element.

How do we find this "bad" element? we will use Heap. After every element we pass we insert it value and index to both min and max heap (done in log(n)). When you have the i-th element and you want to check if there is someone in the previous last array who break your sequence you can start extract element from the heap until no element is bigger or smaller the originalArr[i] -> take the max index of the extract element and that your k - the index of the element who broke your sequence.

I will try to simplify with pseudo code (I only demonstrate for min-heap but it the same as the max heap)

```
    Array is input array of size n
    min-heap = new heap()
    maxLen = array(n) // of size n
    maxLen[0] = 1; //max subArray for original Array with size 1
    min-heap.push(Array[0], 0)
    for (i in (1,n)) {
         if (Array[i] - min-heap.top < m) // then all good
              maxLen[i] = maxLen[i-1] + 1
         else {
              maxIndex = min-heap.top.index;
              while (Array[i] - min-heap.top.value > m)
                     maxIndex = max (maxIndex , min-heap.pop.index)
                     if (empty(min-heap))
                           maxIndex = i // all element are "bad" so need to start new sub-array
                           break 
              //max index is our k ->
              maxLen[i] = i - k + 1
         } 
         min-heap.push(Array[i], i)
```

When you done, run on your max length array and choose the max value (from his index you can extract the begin an end indexes of the original array).

So we had loop over the array (n) and in each insert to 2 heaps (log n). 
You would probably saying: Hi! But you also had un-know times of heap extract which force heapify (log n)! But notice that this heap can have max of n element and element can be extract twice so calculate accumolate complecsity and you will see its still o(1). 
So bottom line: O(n*logn).

**Edited:**

This solution can be simplify by using AVL tree instead of 2 heaps - finding min and max are both O(logn) in AVL tree - same goes for insert, find and delete - so just use tree with element of the value and there index in the original array.

**Edited 2:**

@Fei Xiang even came up with better solution of O(n) using deques.

Comment: In the beginning, both heaps are empty right? Then how can we compare the first element in our array to the top of those heaps?

Comment: "update the max length for that place in last sequence + 1 (this mean your sequence not harm and you can keep up)", can you please explain what you mean by this?

Comment: " when you satisfy the condition, insert back again last node and update current max length with the index of the heap-top till current location."  the max length is the distance from the location of the element at the top of the heap to the current location?

Comment: @Rockstar5645 - update the answer - now its more simple - let me know if there are still hard-to-understand parts...

Comment: @DavidWinder You can improve this to `O(n)` by using increasing/decreasing double-ended queues instead of heaps. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690008/9254539).

Answer (score 1):

I have an improvement to David Winder's algorithm. The idea is that instead of using two heaps to find the minimum and maximum elements, we can use what I call the deque DP optimization trick (there's probably a proper name for this somewhere).

To understand this, we can look at a simpler problem: finding the minimum element in all subarrays of some size `k` in an array. The idea is that we keep a double-ended queue containing potential candidates for the minimum element. When we encounter a new element, we pop off all the elements at the back end of the queue more than or equal to the current element before pushing the current element into the back.

We can do this because we know that any subarray we encounter in the future which includes an element that we pop off will also include the current element, and since the current element is less than those elements that gets popped off, those elements will never be the minimum.

After pushing the current element, we pop off the front element in the queue if it is more than `k` elements away. The minimum element in the current subarray is simply the first element in the queue because the way we popped off the elements from the back of the queue kept it increasing.

To use this algorithm in your problem, we would have two deques to store the minimum and maximum elements. When we encounter a new element which is too much larger than the minimum element, we pop off the front of the deque until the element is no longer too large. The beginning of the longest array ending at that position is then the index of the last element we popped off plus 1.

This makes the solution `O(n)`.

C++ implementation:

```cpp
int best = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest(), beg = 0;
//best = length of the longest subarray that meets the requirements so far
//beg = the beginning of the longest subarray ending at the current index
std::deque<int> least, greatest;
//these two deques store the indices of the elements which could cause trouble
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    while (!least.empty() && a[least.back()] >= a[i])
    {
        least.pop_back();
        //we can pop this off since any we encounter subarray which includes this
        //in the future will also include the current element
    }
    least.push_back(i);
    while (!greatest.empty() && a[greatest.back()] <= a[i])
    {
        greatest.pop_back();
        //we can pop this off since any we encounter subarray which includes this
        //in the future will also include the current element
    }
    greatest.push_back(i);
    while (a[least.front()] < a[i] - m)
    {
        beg = least.front() + 1;
        least.pop_front();
        //remove elements from the beginning if they are too small
    }
    while (a[greatest.front()] > a[i] + m)
    {
        beg = greatest.front() + 1;
        greatest.pop_front();
        //remove elements from the beginning if they are too large
    }
    best = std::max(best, i - beg + 1);
}
```

Comment: I think your code need small modification - consider `array(10,200,20,70,100); k=50`. when hitting index 3 (val=100) the beg will be 3 after 3th while loop but will reduce to 2 in the 4th while loop => best will be 3 (with 20,70,100)

Comment: @DavidWinder Works fine. Outputs 2.

Comment: Why? when getting to 100 you start pop element of of the least deque until getting to 70 so beg = 3 = 2 + 1 (2 as index of 20). After during the greatest deque pop loop we will stop at 200 -> beg = 2 = 1 + 1 (1 as index of 200). but beg is overrode and not choose by max. Anyway good idea!

Comment: @DavidWinder 200 already got popped off when we encountered 20. If you think about it, at most one of the last two while loops will run in each iteration which is why I directly assigned to `beg` instead of taking the max. You can't have an element that's both greater than the minimum plus `m` and less than the maximum minus `m` at the same time because the minimum and the maximum element will differ by at most `m`.